# What is the definition of a "characterized subject"

Tags: subjects

Here is a sentence from my exam:

> "Thinking good examples can be quite difficult"

The subject is "thinking good examples" but my teacher defines it as also a "characterized subject".

How do we conclude what is a "characterized subject"?

Comment: I've never heard of a 'characterized subject'.

Comment: Also, "Thinking good examples" sounds wrong, if not grammatically incorrect. In my opinion, a preposition is missing there, "about", "of", etc.

Comment: @LironIlayev It is incorrect. It would be OK if it were "thinking good thoughts", but we can't "think" an example. We can think **of** an example, or think **about** an example. I can't think of something we think other than thoughts.

Comment: I see the original text says "thinking up good examples". Here is a copy of the text and the different subject levels Thinking up good examples can be quite difficult. (Characterised S)
The cinema was torn down in the 80s. (Affected S)
Quickly and efficiently, the tractor cleared away the rubble. (Instrument S)
In the middle of the empty lot, some dogs were nosing an empty plastic bag.
(Agent S)
The day was getting hotter by the minute. (Characterised S)

Comment: I discovered has to do with the semantic roles of the subject.

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/underx/semantic-roles